# jQuery: hide element after it has been shown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this strange scenario that I cannot understand.

Basically, I show an element using jquery `show();` which works fine.

But I need to `hide()` the same element using the `hide();` function but the element stays visible and the hide() doesn't work.

Can someone please advice on this?

Here is a working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8phpro4L/).

This is my code:

```
$(document).on('click','.buildExMain', function(e){
$(this).children('.buildExDrop').show();
});


$(document).on('click','.pSelection', function(e){

$('.buildExDrop').hide();
});
```

Comment: it's because the event is propagating and triggering the handler which shows the elements, you can use `e.stopPropagation()` in your handler which hides the elements - https://jsfiddle.net/8phpro4L/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@billyonecan was spot on, adding `e.stopPropagation();` after your `$('.buildExDrop').hide();` fixes this.

This allows the hide click event for the sub-elements `.pSelection` to not bubble up to the show click event of the `.buildExDrop` element.

Answer (score 1):

Your click to hide also triggers the click to show. this works

```
$(function(){
$(document).on('click','.buildExMain span', function(e){
$('.buildExDrop').show();
});


$(".buildExMain").on('click','.pSelection', function(){
$('.buildExDrop').hide();
});
});
```